# Conditionally count based on other field data in SSRS Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

I am working SSRS report, I have a field named as `Details` and I would like to get the count of other field `SerialNumber`.

So in short I want to get the total count of `SerialNumber` which has no `Details`.

I tried below but not working. It always give the total count count without considering blank `Details`

```
=CStr(COUNT(IIF(Not(IsNothing(Fields!Details.Value)),Fields!SerialNumber.Value,0)))
```

How can I achieve this by expression? Please help.

Comment: Note performing a logical negation using `Not` operator in `isNothing` function. You actually need the null `Details` values not the `not null`. Try: `COUNT(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Details.Value),Fields!SerialNumber.Value,Nothing))`

Comment: Share a sample of your dataset and the expected results in order to reproduce your issue.

Comment: thanks @alejandrozuleta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with my data. In dataset I was fetching rows based on `Isnull()` like below

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN 'Y'='Y' THEN ISNULL(Code ,'') + '  ' + ISNULL(Description ,'')
            ELSE CASE 
                      WHEN ISNULL(Code ,'')='' THEN ISNULL(RefCharge ,'') 
                          +'  '+ISNULL(RefDescription ,'')
                      ELSE ISNULL(Code ,'')+'  '+ISNULL(Description ,'')
                 END
       END               AS Details
```

So it was showing  (3 blank spaces) and my expression was.

```
=COUNT(IIF(Fields!Details.Value<>"",Fields!Number.Value,Nothing))
```

Finally I tried below, now it's working fine now.

```
=COUNT(IIF(Trim(Fields!Details.Value)<>"",Fields!Number.Value,Nothing))
```

***Note:*** *So I have noted that whenever we need to check such kind of conditions we must have to use [**`Trim()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h9wz3dez%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)*